# How can I set columns to take full ag-grid width when I have 2 columns in columnDefs?

Tags: ag-grid

I am building columnDefs dynamically and it sometimes contains 2 columns or more than 2 columns.
I want 2 columns to take full width of ng-grid. I have tried autoSizeColumns but it is not working and 2 columns are not occupying the full width of the ag-grid.

```js
columnDefs = [
  {
    "headerName": "Term/KMs",
    "field": "termkms",
    "sortable": false,
    "filter": false,
    "lockPosition": true,
    "cellRenderer:" "asteriskCellRendererFunc(params)"
    "cellStyle": {
      "color": "#fff",
      "text-align": "center",
      "background-color": "#4a5568",
      "font-size": "1rem",
      "padding-left": ".5rem",
      "padding-right": ".5rem",
      "padding-top": ".5rem",
      "padding-bottom": ".5rem",
      "font-weight": "700",
      "border-width": "1px",
      "border-color": "#cbd5e0"
    },
    "resizable": true
  },
  {
    "headerName": "250,000 kms",
    "field": "250,000",
    "sortable": true,
    "filter": true,
    "resizable": true
  }
]
```

```html
<ag-grid-angular
        #agGrid
        id="myGrid"
        style="width: 100%;"
        class="ag-theme-alpine"
        [rowHeight]="70"
        [rowData]="this.rowData"
        [columnDefs]="this.columnDefs"
        (cellClicked)="onCellClicked($event)"
        domLayout='autoHeight'
        (firstDataRendered)="onFirstDataRendered($event)"
      >
      </ag-grid-angular>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [Column Flex](https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-grid/column-sizing/#column-flex):

E.g.

```
<ag-grid-angular
    // [...]
    [defaultColDef]="defaultColDef"
    >
</ag-grid-angular>
```

```
defaultColDef = {
    flex:1,
    minWidth:100
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Appreciated.

Comment: I always wanted to note that you can set these values for the `ColDef`s as well. This is useful if your columns aren't dynamic.